# How is compiled pattern different from regular pattern in python RE?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I find compiled pattern doesn't work in some case.
For example

```
import re
s1 = 'one two three four'
s2 = 'five six seven eight'
p = re.compile(r'^five')
m = p.search(s1 + '\n' + s2, re.MULTILINE)
```

returns None

Whereas

```
s1 = 'one two three four'
s2 = 'five six seven eight'
m = re.search('^five', s1 + '\n' + s2, re.MULTILINE)
```

returns a match.

What gets changed while a pattern is compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just that you're putting your flags in the wrong place. If you want to use flags with a compiled regex, you pass them when you create it:

```
In [4]: import re
   ...: s1 = 'one two three four'
   ...: s2 = 'five six seven eight'
   ...: p = re.compile(r'^five', re.MULTILINE)
   ...: m = p.search(s1 + '\n' + s2)
   ...: print(m)
   ...:
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(19, 23), match='five'>
```

The reason you're not getting an error is that `re.MULTILINE` is a subclass of `int`, which the compiled regex's `search` method is interpreting as its second positional argument, `pos`.

Comment: `re.MULTILINE` isn't a subclass of `int`, it is an `int`. `re.MULTILINE` == 8

Comment: @abccd In Python 3.6 it certainly is: `In [59]: re.MULTILINE
Out[59]: <RegexFlag.MULTILINE: 8>`

Comment: Hum, I guess they changed it (we got [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntFlag) to thank). In Python 3.5, it was represented by just int 8 since `enum.IntFlag` was only introduced in Python 3.6.

Comment: Yes indeed: "Changed in version 3.6: Flag constants are now instances of RegexFlag, which is a subclass of enum.IntFlag."